# MVC3 DataType.Date EditorFor Outputting the Wrong Class in HTML

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, datepicker, editorfor

I have an MVC3 project. I have 2 model classes. Lets call them FooYes and FooNo.

I created controllers for each.

I created CRUD views for both.

I then implemented the jQuery DatePicker according to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx). I only implemented the picker part and not the validation.

In my FooYes edit.cshtml the date picker works fine. In the edit.cshtml for FooNo it doesn't.

The only difference I found is in the classes that get output for the models:

FooYes looks like this in the final html:

```
<input class="date"
```

FooNo looks like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line"
```

Here is the model for FooYes:

```
    [Display(Name = "Creation Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

Here is the model for FooNo:

```
    [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public virtual DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
```

As you can see the declaration is the same in the model, so that can't be it. I even tried copy and paste the ExpirationDate property from FooNo into FooYes and duplicated all the stuff from FooNo to FooYes inside of FooYes and it WORKED then. So it is not the code in the model

Here is the code from the .cshtml:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreationDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreationDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreationDate)
    </div>
```

The only thing different between this and the other is the name of the field.

When I look at the source html in the final result the headers, includes, links, everything is exactly the same except in the one that doesn't work the class= is set to the text thing instead of date.

I am totally confused. Anyone have any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: LOL, I had a feeling that as soon as I posted a question I would figure it out. That just happened.

The problem is that the EditorTemplates folder with the Date.cshtml partial view needs to be in EACH Views/{controller}/ folder.

So I have a new question....is there any way to have a global EditorTemplates folder that covers ALL of my controller subfolders?

Comment: You really should ask a new question, so that people can find it when they search.  StackOverflow is about community, and do your part.  However, DMac answered your question.

Comment: If you put the template in Views\Shared\EditorTemplates then it will be picked up for all controllers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really just followed [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx), the reason why it didn't work is because the selector to set up the datepicker only includes `.date`. Try changing the JavaScript to:

```
$('.date, .text-box.single-line').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
```

And see if it works. If it does, you may want to think about revising the textbox generated for FooNo, as `.text-box.single-line` seems like a generate class, which may be shared by other textboxes which are not intended to be datepickers.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment, you can have the `Date.cshtml` template be global by putting it in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` directory